# class template constructor overload resolution ambiguity

Tags: c++, class-template

I'm writing a class template like stl vector,and two constructors are like this:

```
template<class T>
vector<T>::vector(size_t count, const T&value) :bg(new T[count]),
ed(bg + count), cap(ed) {
    for (auto it = bg; it != ed; ++it)
        *it = value;
}//bg ed cap are all T*

template<class T>
template<class Input>
vector<T>::vector(Input first, Input second) : bg(new T[second - first]),
ed(bg + (second - first)), cap(ed) {
    memcpy(bg, (void*)first, sizeof(T)*(second - first));
}
```

so if I do this

```
vector<int>v(2,0)
```

complier gives me error,it seems like the program uses the second constructor instead of the first.
can anyone explain why? the stl vector says

> This overload only participates in overload resolution if InputIt
>   satisfies LegacyInputIterator, to avoid ambiguity with the overload
>   (3).

so how can I change my code to avoid this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Use [standard type-traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) and [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second overload is chosen because it better matches the argument types when `Input` is `int`. Specifically, given the arguments `(int, int)`, the overload `(int, int)` is a better match than the overload `(size_t, int const&)`. Note that if you change the first parameter of the first overload from `size_t` to `int`, it will be chosen instead.

If you want to disable the function template overload when `Input` is an input iterator, you can exploit [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) using [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if):

```
template <
    typename InputIt,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_base_of_v<
            std::input_iterator_tag,
            typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::iterator_category>>>
vector(InputIt, InputIt)
{
}
```

You can optionally extract the logic out into a type trait.

```
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct is_input_iterator : std::false_type
{
};

template <typename T>
struct is_input_iterator<T, std::void_t<typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category>>
: std::is_base_of<
    std::input_iterator_tag,
    typename std::iterator_traits<T>::iterator_category>
{
};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_input_iterator_v = is_input_iterator<T>::value;
```

Then the function definition becomes a bit more readable.

```
template <
    typename InputIt,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<is_input_iterator_v<InputIt>>>
vector(InputIt, InputIt)
{
}
```